# Sitecore CSS and Javascript Version Control

Tags: javascript, css, version-control, sitecore

I'm using Sitecore v7.0 and think of setting version controller in Sitecore.
We can easily set the Version control in physical system location, but if we add .css and .js files into media folder, it would be hard to track version control because Sitecore calls all files in media tree from its physical cache location.

**Is there any idea to set Version Control for .css and .js files in media library?**

I don't think this is good system structure, right?:

1. Create RichText box
2. Put all .css or .js contents
3. Get the contents as css or javascript MimeType.
4. Setting workflow for this item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would just place CSS and JavaScript files within your VS solution and use whatever version control system you have for your other code.

There is not *specific* functionality for handling CSS/JS files in Sitecore - you *could* put them into the media library as you mentioned but I would not recommend this. If you absolutely have to place some CSS/JS into Sitecore I would create specific content items for this using items with a 'Memo' or 'Multiline text' field type to store the CSS/JS content. You could as you mentioned, use a specific workflow for these items and also set different access rights to prevent any editor from modifying them.

If what you need is varying themes/behaviours for different sections of your site, you might be better off using some logic to check the type of the current page/item (by checking template type, or some other field value) and then load the relevant JS/CSS files (defined in your solution) for that page.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, version controlling/workflowing assets is probably not the best idea. You're introducing overhead for very little benefit, and these types of files are static 99.9% of the time. Also, you're expecting (generally) a technical lay-person to be the one confirming changes (are your publishers really familiar enough with CSS/JavaScript to place something in an Approved workflow?)

If you're looking for this kind of granularity, take the standard approach and use `asset-1.0.0.css` and up-rev the flat file name. When you go to make changes, reference `asset-1.0.1.css` (then on publish the new file will be used). This is how jQuery, Twitter Bootstrap and other libraries handle versioning.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, could you make some detail about your mention in granularity??

Comment: @Jay: Granularity in the context of versioned assets. e.j. jQuery 1.10.9, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, etc (Same goes with any js/css files).

Comment: Thank you! now I see what you meant.